# How to fix "Value was either too large or too small for a UInt32" C#

Tags: c#, actionscript-3

I am trying to convert ActionScript3 code to C# that's like the main thing. However, with trying to convert one of the functions I got the error which is in the title when I was trying to convert a hexadecimal string to an int.

Basically, this code is supposed to take information for example user data and then do somethings and in the end return Base64 encoded text. The main error that I am aware of is at the part where "loc9 = Convert.ToInt32(loc8, 16);" is as that is where I am getting the error said in the title. I have tried researching similar issues others have had with something like this, but it just didn't seem the same and didn't really help me out.

(Btw I am sorry if this doesn't sound so clear, correct me or ask more questions if not understood)

[Screenshot of error when called](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0L9d5.png)

[image]

My C# Code:

```cs
private static string hasher(string input)
        {
            MD5 md5 = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create();
            byte[] inputBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input);
            byte[] hash = md5.ComputeHash(inputBytes);


            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < hash.Length; i++)
            {
                sb.Append(hash[i].ToString("x2"));
            }

            return sb.ToString();

        }

        public static string p(string param1)
        {
            var loc6 = "";
            var loc7 = "";
            var loc8 = "";
            var loc9 = 0;
            var loc2 = hasher(param1);
            var loc4 = 0;

            MemoryStream loc0 = new MemoryStream();
            var loc3 = new byte[] { };
            while(loc4 < loc2.Length * 2)
            {
                loc6 = loc2.Substring(loc4, loc4 + 1);
                loc7 = loc2.Substring(loc4 + 1, loc4 + 2);
                loc8 = "0x" + loc6 + loc7;
                loc9 = Convert.ToInt32(loc8, 16);
                new BinaryWriter(loc0).Write(loc9);
                loc4 = loc4 + 2;
            }
            loc0.Position = 0;
            loc3 = loc0.ToArray();
            return Convert.ToBase64String(loc3, 0, 16);
        }

        public string calculateFromNewActorCreationData(string username, string password, byte[] small, byte[] full)
        {
            return calculateFromStrings(username, password, small, full);
        }

        public string calculateFromStrings(string param1, string param2, object param3, object param4)
        {
            var loc5 = param1 + param2 + fromByteArray(param3 as byte[]) + fromByteArray(param4 as byte[]) + p();
            return p(loc5);
        }

        private string fromByteArray(byte[] param1)
        {
            var ms = new MemoryStream(param1);
            List<byte> list2 = new List<byte>();
            if (param1.Length <= 20)
                return HexStringFromBytes(param1);
            var loc3 = new byte[] { };
            var loc4 = param1.Length / 20;
            var loc5 = 0;
            while (loc5 < 20)
            {
                ms.Position = loc4 * loc5;
                list2.Add(new BinaryReader(ms).ReadByte());
                loc5++;
            }
            loc3 = list2.ToArray();
            return HexStringFromBytes(loc3);
        }

        private static string HexStringFromBytes(byte[] bytes)
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (byte b in bytes)
            {
                var hex = b.ToString("x2");
                sb.Append(hex);
            }
            return sb.ToString();
        }

        private string p()
        {
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
            new BinaryWriter(stream).Write(120);
            new BinaryWriter(stream).Write(-38);
            new BinaryWriter(stream).Write(99);
            new BinaryWriter(stream).Write(16);
            new BinaryWriter(stream).Write(32);
            new BinaryWriter(stream).Write(51);
            new BinaryWriter(stream).Write(41);
            new BinaryWriter(stream).Write(-110);
            new BinaryWriter(stream).Write(12);
            new BinaryWriter(stream).Write(50);
            new BinaryWriter(stream).Write(81);
            new BinaryWriter(stream).Write(73);
            new BinaryWriter(stream).Write(49);
            new BinaryWriter(stream).Write(-56);
            new BinaryWriter(stream).Write(13);
            new BinaryWriter(stream).Write(48);
            new BinaryWriter(stream).Write(54);
            new BinaryWriter(stream).Write(54);
            new BinaryWriter(stream).Write(14);
            new BinaryWriter(stream).Write(48);
            new BinaryWriter(stream).Write(46);
            new BinaryWriter(stream).Write(2);
            new BinaryWriter(stream).Write(0);
            new BinaryWriter(stream).Write(45);
            new BinaryWriter(stream).Write(-30);
            new BinaryWriter(stream).Write(4);
            new BinaryWriter(stream).Write(-16);
            stream.Position = 0;
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray());
        }
```

ActionScript3 Code:

```
private static function p(param1:String) : String
      {
         var _loc6_:String = null;
         var _loc7_:String = null;
         var _loc8_:String = null;
         var _loc9_:int = 0;
         var _loc2_:String = MD5.hash(param1);
         var _loc3_:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
         var _loc4_:int = 0;
         while(_loc4_ < _loc2_.length * 2)
         {
            _loc6_ = _loc2_.slice(_loc4_,_loc4_ + 1);
            _loc7_ = _loc2_.slice(_loc4_ + 1,_loc4_ + 2);
            _loc8_ = "0x" + _loc6_ + _loc7_;
            _loc9_ = int(_loc8_);
            _loc3_.writeByte(_loc9_);
            _loc4_ = _loc4_ + 2;
         }
         _loc3_.position = 0;
         var _loc5_:Base64Encoder = new Base64Encoder();
         _loc5_.encodeBytes(_loc3_,0,16);
         return _loc5_.toString();
      }

      public function calculateFromNewActorCreationData(param1:NewActorCreationData, param2:ByteArray, param3:ByteArray) : String
      {
         return this.calculateFromStrings(param1.ChosenActorName,param1.ChosenPassword,param2,param3);
      }

      public function calculateFromStrings(param1:String, param2:String, param3:Object, param4:Object) : String
      {
         var _loc5_:String = param1 + param2 + this.fromByteArray(param3) + this.fromByteArray(param4) + this.p();
         return p(_loc5_);
      }

      private function fromByteArray(param1:Object) : String
      {
         if(param1 == null)
         {
            return "";
         }
         var _loc2_:int = 20;
         if(param1.length <= _loc2_)
         {
            return Hex.fromArray(param1 as ByteArray);
         }
         var _loc3_:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
         var _loc4_:int = param1.length / _loc2_;
         var _loc5_:int = 0;
         while(_loc5_ < _loc2_)
         {
            param1.position = _loc4_ * _loc5_;
            _loc3_.writeByte(param1.readByte());
            _loc5_++;
         }
         return Hex.fromArray(_loc3_);
      }

      private function p() : String
      {
         var _loc1_:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
         _loc1_.writeByte(120);
         _loc1_.writeByte(-38);
         _loc1_.writeByte(99);
         _loc1_.writeByte(16);
         _loc1_.writeByte(12);
         _loc1_.writeByte(51);
         _loc1_.writeByte(41);
         _loc1_.writeByte(-118);
         _loc1_.writeByte(12);
         _loc1_.writeByte(50);
         _loc1_.writeByte(81);
         _loc1_.writeByte(73);
         _loc1_.writeByte(49);
         _loc1_.writeByte(-56);
         _loc1_.writeByte(13);
         _loc1_.writeByte(48);
         _loc1_.writeByte(54);
         _loc1_.writeByte(54);
         _loc1_.writeByte(14);
         _loc1_.writeByte(48);
         _loc1_.writeByte(46);
         _loc1_.writeByte(2);
         _loc1_.writeByte(0);
         _loc1_.writeByte(45);
         _loc1_.writeByte(-30);
         _loc1_.writeByte(4);
         _loc1_.writeByte(-16);
         _loc1_.uncompress();
         _loc1_.position = 0;
         return _loc1_.readUTF();
      }
```

What I am expecting in the end is to be able to call the function having the returned Base64 encoded data show in a MessageBox (using messagebox as a test) instead of any errors popping up.

P.S - Besides the main problem I am having with this code, I also feel like the other functions I had converted aren't perfect or just might not be the same. So, if my main problem can be solved, if someone can also double check the other functions of my code make sure they are accurate that would be amazing and thanks in advance.

Comment: The obvious asumption would be that the value is too big or too small. That p function writes down 27 binary values. If you try to fit something that long into a UInt64, of course it will not fit. 1 Hex character represents 4 bit. So anything longer the 16 hex digits and it will not work. If you need arbitrary numbers, there is the BigInteger structure: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @mjwills oh wait i am so sorry, i just ran again and it says UInt32. I remember it saying UInt64 before I edited some of the code before posting it so that's just what I thought. this is the error: http://prntscr.com/osbtw7  and here is the test code http://prntscr.com/osbu25

Comment: @mjwills by the looks of it the value is "0xf0e6c0e6c23" I would guess this is defo too big just like how Christopher said, so do you think trying to use BigInteger would be the best thing to do?

Comment: 0xf0e6c0e6c23 is 44 bits and bigger than an Int32. Try a long or Int64. Also post the [actual error message](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/) to your question, do not try to paraphrase the message or guess what it means.

Comment: If the error is about a `U-INT32` why do you think it's caused by converting to `INT32`?

Comment: @VC.One I am just trying to convert the ActionScript3 code to C#. in the as3 code for that part it does int(loc8); and im pretty sure if i am saying this correctly int() in as3 is converting the hexadecimal string (loc8) to a int32 so i thought doing what I did would basically do the same thing but it turns out it didn't lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at this overall, it appears the AS3 code is attempting to convert the `MD5.hash` result into a Base64 encoded string in the worst way possible (I believe it can be done in one line.)

So, instead of copying all the code to translate the hash to a hex string only to poorly translate it back to a binary array, just use the C# result which is already a binary array directly:

```
public static string p(string param1) {
    byte[] loc3 = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create().ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(param1));
    return Convert.ToBase64String(loc3, 0, 16);
}
```

Comment: hello, i decided to try and do all of those options that you suggested in which yes it did help for part of the issue, but now i have a new one.

for me loc2 = "8e63f0e6c23e79be479ea888974b0186" and so doing lets say "loc8 = "0x" + loc2.Substring(loc4, 2);" would keep giving like "0x8e" etc which fixed the main error.

However now i got "System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index and length must refer to a location within the string.
Parameter name: length". I would guess this would be because there is nothing else to look for in the MD5 hash. Could you help me fix this one?

Comment: @Desource Looking more closely, it looks like the AS3 code is an incredibly stupid way to convert the `MD5.hash` string into a byte array to be converted to Base64, which can be done in one line of AS3. Similarly, in C# the result of `md5.ComputeHash` is already a `byte[]` so just use the `Convert.ToBase64String` on that result and skip all the conversion to/from ASCII encoded hex.

Comment: @Desource I replaced my answer after looking at the overall AS3 function.

Comment: thank you for doing that for me, fixed the errors i was having. If you don't mind can you please look at the other p() function in the AS3 code and see if you can convert that for me to C# as idk i feel like my way of doing that is not accurate. it would mean a lot if i can just find out if it's right or not and thanks in advance (: @NetMage

Comment: i tried doing something like:
 MemoryStream loc1 = new MemoryStream();
            loc1.WriteByte((byte)120);
            loc1.WriteByte((byte)~-38);
            loc1.WriteByte((byte)99);
            loc1.WriteByte((byte)16);
            loc1.WriteByte((byte)12);
            loc1.WriteByte((byte)51);
            loc1.WriteByte((byte)41);
            loc1.WriteByte((byte)~-118); etc etc (even trying to make the negatives a byte)

and then returning Encoding.UTF8.GetString(loc1); however i noticed the _loc1_.uncompress() and idek what do do about that. @NetMage

Comment: @NetMage the Asker's working with decompiled AS3 code. Most likely it was a one-liner before compiling and then whatever decompiler was used made that messy function from machine code. Also in AS3 once a variable `= null` it's up for Garbage Collection and so cannot be used again (compiler errors with _"You cannot update a null variable"_ or similar). That posted Question code would never re-compile even in AS3 itself so it's amazing you fixed it... with one line in C#!! Ka-pow!!

Comment: @Desource please [mark the solution as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86979). It shows "Thanks" to the Answerer and let's others know there is a working solution here.

Comment: @VC.One Very interesting, though I believe they could have used the AS3 `MD5.digest` and gotten rid of all that code. I assume the AS3 compiler wouldn't inline that function call.

Comment: @Desource You should write another question if you want advice on the other function.

Comment: @NetMage https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57532311/what-is-bytearray-uncompress-in-as3-equivalent-to-in-c best question I could come up with lmao