# What is "ByteArray.uncompress()" in AS3 equivalent to in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, actionscript-3

I am trying to convert a AS3 (ActionScript 3) function to C#.

This ActionScript function contains a class called ByteArray which from what I am aware of it's basically what it sounds like lmao. I think it's kind of similar of how byte[] would be in C#. Anyway, I have tried my best to convert the code to C# using MemoryStream and then writing bytes to it, and then returning UTF8 string as you can see in my code below. However, I feel as if my way of doing how the ActionScript code does isn't accurate and that is where my question above comes in.

With them negative numbers being written into "loc1" (The ByteArray) and "loc1.uncompress()", that's where I feel like I am failing and was wondering if someone could help me out in converting this function so it's fully accurate?

On top of that question, I would also like to ask if what I was doing with the negative numbers was correct in my C# code just like how the ActionScript code was doing it? Would mean a lot (:

(Sorry if not fully understandable and if what I say doesn't match up as much)

ActionScript Code:

```
private function p() : String
      {
         var _loc1_:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
         _loc1_.writeByte(120);
         _loc1_.writeByte(-38);
         _loc1_.writeByte(99);
         _loc1_.writeByte(16);
         _loc1_.writeByte(12);
         _loc1_.writeByte(51);
         _loc1_.writeByte(41);
         _loc1_.writeByte(-118);
         _loc1_.writeByte(12);
         _loc1_.writeByte(50);
         _loc1_.writeByte(81);
         _loc1_.writeByte(73);
         _loc1_.writeByte(49);
         _loc1_.writeByte(-56);
         _loc1_.writeByte(13);
         _loc1_.writeByte(48);
         _loc1_.writeByte(54);
         _loc1_.writeByte(54);
         _loc1_.writeByte(14);
         _loc1_.writeByte(48);
         _loc1_.writeByte(46);
         _loc1_.writeByte(2);
         _loc1_.writeByte(0);
         _loc1_.writeByte(45);
         _loc1_.writeByte(-30);
         _loc1_.writeByte(4);
         _loc1_.writeByte(-16);
         _loc1_.uncompress();
         _loc1_.position = 0;
         return _loc1_.readUTF();
      }
```

My C# Code:

```cs
public string p()
        {
            MemoryStream loc1 = new MemoryStream();
            loc1.WriteByte((byte)120);
            loc1.WriteByte((byte)~-38);
            loc1.WriteByte((byte)99);
            loc1.WriteByte((byte)16);
            loc1.WriteByte((byte)12);
            loc1.WriteByte((byte)51);
            loc1.WriteByte((byte)41);
            loc1.WriteByte((byte)~-118);
            loc1.WriteByte((byte)12);
            loc1.WriteByte((byte)50);
            loc1.WriteByte((byte)81);
            loc1.WriteByte((byte)73);
            loc1.WriteByte((byte)49);
            loc1.WriteByte((byte)~-56);
            loc1.WriteByte((byte)13);
            loc1.WriteByte((byte)48);
            loc1.WriteByte((byte)54);
            loc1.WriteByte((byte)54);
            loc1.WriteByte((byte)14);
            loc1.WriteByte((byte)48);
            loc1.WriteByte((byte)46);
            loc1.WriteByte((byte)2);
            loc1.WriteByte((byte)0);
            loc1.WriteByte((byte)45);
            loc1.WriteByte((byte)~-30);
            loc1.WriteByte((byte)4);
            loc1.WriteByte((byte)~-16);
            loc1.Position = 0;
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(loc1.ToArray());
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**(1)**
@Jimmy has given you a good Answer.
This is what he meant when he told you *"to mask with `0xFF`"* so that your `-38` becomes masked as:

```
loc1.WriteByte( (byte)(-38 & 0xFF) );
```

Do the same above logic for any other values that have a minus `sign`.

**(2)**
It might be easier if you just use values written in **hex** instead of **decimal**. This means instead of decimal `255` you write equivalent hex of `0xFF` since bytes are supposed to be in hex. The `WriteByte` is auto-converting your decimals but it's not helping you to learn what it is going on...

For example your beginning two byte values are `120 -38` but in hex that is `0x78 0xDA`.
Now if you google search [bytes 0x78 0xDA](https://www.google.com/search?safe=strict&ei=AURYXba4N8HWkwXjhrigDA&q=bytes+%220x78+0xDA%22) you will find out those two bytes are header for ZLIB's `DEFLATE` compression algorithm.

This ZLIB detail is important to know for the next step...

**(3)**
Sometimes the variable names are **not always recovered during de-compiling**. This is why all your code has these silly `_loc_` as generic names (real var names are unknown, only their data type).

Your `_loc1_.uncompress();` is supposed to contain a `String` variable specifying the algorithm.

> `public function uncompress(algorithm:String) :void` //from AS3 documentation

During decompilation that important info was lost. Luckily there only 3 options `"ZLIB"`, "`DEFLATE`" or "`LZMA`". From the above **notice (2)** we can see it should be  `_loc1_.uncompress("DEFLATE");`

**Solution:**

Create a byte array (not Memory Stream) and manually fill with hex values (*eg:* `-13` is written `0xDA`).

First convert each of your numbers to hex. You can use Windows Calculator in `Programmer` mode (under `View` option), where you type a decimal in **dec** mode then press **hex** to see same value as hex format. Maybe some online tool can do it too.

The final hex values should look like `78 DA 63 10 0C 33 29 8A 0C 32 51 49 31 C8 .... etc` until the ending hex value `F0` which equals your ending decimal `-16`.

Then you can easily do...

```
public string p()
{

    byte[] loc_Data = new byte[] {
    0x78, 0xDA, 0x63, 0x10, 0x0C, 0x33, 0x29, 0x8A, 
    0x0C, 0x32, 0x51, 0x49, 0x31, 0xC8, 0x0D, 0x30, etc etc ... until 0xF0
    };

    var loc_Uncompressed = Ionic.Zlib.ZlibStream.UncompressBuffer( loc_Data );
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString( loc_Uncompressed ); //or try: loc_Uncompressed.ToArray()

}
```

Comment: hello again, I tried doing what you said, I converted all the numbers needed to hex and then I did the uncompressbuffer function and so on. Unfortunately that did not work for me as I am getting an error from that function which says "Ionic.Zlib.ZlibException: Bad state (incorrect data check)." is there any way of fixing this?

Comment: oh yes and btw I even tried doing the first thing you said which was masking the negative numbers, but I get the same result as I would get with the way I already done it so either way that option would of been useless. on top of that when I went to uncompress with that it just returned nothing lol.

Comment: Zlib data can be chunked, it's possible your data is incomplete (needs other chunks). You have 27 bytes but only the first 19 bytes work. From those 19 bytes, the first two cannot be text so the remaining 17 bytes make `V4rYR4$d0mP333P3r`. Do with that info whatever your plan was when you started your project.

Comment: lad thank you so f***ing much everything finally works woooooooooo lmao @VC.One

Answer (score 1):

1) In C#, bytes are unsigned. You cannot convert a signed byte to an unsigned byte with the complement, because your intention is that the bitwise representation should be identical, rather than opposite, which is what the complement does.

one simple way to convert is to mask with `0xFF`: `-37 & 0xFF = 219`. There are other, mathematically equivalent ways, such as checking for negatives with `sbyte sb = -37; byte b = sb < 0 ? 256 + sb : sb;`

2) The builtin System.IO.Compression namespace is lacking in a number of ways. For one, it doesn't even support decompressing zlib data, which is what your byte array holds. the best way is to use a third party package on Nuget instead. The [DotNetZip](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DotNetZip/1.13.3) library does what you need, specifically the `Ionic.Zlib.ZlibStream.UncompressBuffer` function.

Comment: Hello, I understand what you mean in the top part with bytes being unsigned and then not being able to convert an sbyte to byte like how I did my fault there lol. I also did the bottom part which was installing DotNetZip package. However, everything else I don't think I will be able to understand unless you were to like turn it into functions or something like that and then show me what you came up with. It would help a lot if you could do that for me as it would help me understand better. Thanks as well for trying to help me out with this (: