# How can I write bytes with -?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I want to make a **checksum** but I need to know the last string which is written as UTF and is also then compressed. I am writing these bytes into a C# **MemoryStream**.

I can't decompress it because I can't write C# bytes with a minus sign `-` (eg: a `-16` or `-56`).

Can someone help?

### ActionScript (Flash) code:

```
var loc1:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
         loc1.writeByte(120);
         loc1.writeByte(-38);
         loc1.writeByte(99);
         loc1.writeByte(16);
         loc1.writeByte(12);
         loc1.writeByte(51);
         loc1.writeByte(41);
         loc1.writeByte(-118);
         loc1.writeByte(12);
         loc1.writeByte(50);
         loc1.writeByte(81);
         loc1.writeByte(73);
         loc1.writeByte(49);
         loc1.writeByte(-56);
         loc1.writeByte(13);
         loc1.writeByte(48);
         loc1.writeByte(54);
         loc1.writeByte(54);
         loc1.writeByte(14);
         loc1.writeByte(48);
         loc1.writeByte(46);
         loc1.writeByte(2);
         loc1.writeByte(0);
         loc1.writeByte(45);
         loc1.writeByte(-30);
         loc1.writeByte(4);
         loc1.writeByte(-16);
         loc1.uncompress();
         loc1.position = 0;
         return loc1.readUTF();
```

Comment: why does it have c# tag?

Comment: because i want to write it in c#

Comment: it's not included in a question you asked. Plus a code you've provided is not in c# thus it would be hard to find error in non-existing code.

Comment: I want to write this bytes into memorystream in c# but i can't bc vs says (-30,-55) is int but when I convert it to byte then I have another error

Answer (score 1):

For situations where the **single byte** is **signed** with a minus sign:

You can try: `myBytes[ somePosition ] = ( 256 + (-X) ); //where -X is your signed value`.

Looking at first two bytes:

**AS3** code:

```
loc1.writeByte(120); //is 0x78
loc1.writeByte(-38); //is 0xDA
```

The second byte has `-38` so doing a `(256 + (-38)` gives you byte `0xDA`.
 (where `0xDA` has a "unsigned" value of `218` or alternatively is a "signed" value of `-38`).

**C#** code:

```
memStream.WriteByte( 120 );  //writes 0x78
memStream.WriteByte( (256 + (-38)) ); //writes 0xDA
```

So the first two bytes are hex values of: `0x78DA`.

Funnily enough I've seen this before in a ZLIB header. This is what  `loc1.uncompress();` is doing, passing the byte array to a ZLIB decompressor. After decompressing you'll get bytes that represent a UTF String (one byte per String's characters).

Comment: I wrote bytes in memorystream and memorystream ToArray() then I decompressed it using GZipStream and received this: ◄V4rYR4$d0mP333P3r. My checksum with this pass not match with original :/

Comment: [link](https://pastebin.com/raw/dZcArfSR) check out my code

Comment: GZipStream is for `.gz` files but your data would make a `.bz` file (or `.bz2`). You need a Zlib decompressor. Try the [ZlibStream class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.zlibstream?view=net-6.0) (I've never used it) or else use an external library like [SharpZipLib](https://icsharpcode.github.io/SharpZipLib/) (I've used only the AS3 port of same tool and it works nicely) or maybe look for DotNetZip via Google search.

Comment: I'll check what your decompressed bytes should be in about 1 hour (when I got free time to test things out).

Comment: **(1)** Ok my bad after checking it seems `V4rYR4$d0mP333P3r` is **correct output** from Zlib decompression so your GZipStream method was also okay. You also get some strange 2 bytes (or characters) in front of the text, you say it is `◄` but for me I see it as `NUL DC1` in Notepad++ (note how first byte makes a NULL?).  **(2)** What happens if you use just `V4rYR4$d0mP333P3r` in your checksum testing? **(3)** You have to think about `return loc1.readUTF();` what other function is receiving this "returned" data and what does it do with it, _ie:_ Does it skip the first 2 chars or anything else?

Comment: @VC.One please remove "alternatively call abs()" off your post. In case of writing a signed byte, the proper way is to convert it to unsigned by adding 256, or else you won't be writing the intended value, as this sequence needs to be matching between C# and AS3 codes.

Comment: @Vesper thanks for the heads up. I've removed it. My logic was that the alternative to using `+` was to instead just minus the 256 against absolute value _eg:_  `memStream.WriteByte( (256 - Math.Abs(-38)) );` but to be honest the **+** is simpler and cleaner... The asker used the **+** version in [their C# code](https://pastebin.com/raw/dZcArfSR).

Comment: @WojtekKozłowski Did using just `V4rYR4$d0mP333P3r` work for you? It seems someone else asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57532311/2057709)  in the past and that worked for them.

Comment: I will check it

Comment: Thx a lot guys it work!!